# How do I prevent my QGIS Plugin from opening twice?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have made a new QGIS Plugin, almost everything is working fine, but I can click on my Plugin-Button several times and it starts several times. So I see my Plugin 4 or 5 times. How can I prevent that?

Almost no Plugin out there shows this behavior, but I can't figure out what I do have to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a [QDialog](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdialog.html) (you didn't exactly specify what your Plugin opens) you could set it `modal`.

In Qt Designer by ticking the `modal` checkbox:

[image: Qt Designer modal]

Or in the [corresponding `*.py`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdialog.html#setModal):

```
self.setModal(True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, I open a QDialog. I friend of mine helped me to develop a solution for the problem, but I knew that there has to be a very simple way, I just did not know, that the solution is so amazingly simple!!!